# C# TextBox readonly behaves like disabled

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 4 TextBox controls on my form - all 4 have same properties and same event handlers. Only different event handler is TextChanged on 4th control. I have one problem with them - when I set all those textboxes to ReadOnly all 4 become read-only, but 3 of them have a normal white background, and 4th has a grey background (like when you disable them). I have no other code that could cause this bug - any ideas why this could happen or has someone experienced it before?
Here's the code of one textbox

```
this.tbPercentage.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
this.tbPercentage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(99, 151);
this.tbPercentage.MaxLength = 3;
this.tbPercentage.Name = "tbPercentage";
this.tbPercentage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 22);
this.tbPercentage.TabIndex = 1;
this.tbPercentage.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbPercentage_TextChanged);
this.tbPercentage.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.MyTextbox_KeyDown);
this.tbPercentage.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.MyTextbox_KeyPress);
```

Only difference between the 4 text boxes is that 4th has a different TextChanged event handler. If I put it to same as other 3 event handlers it still gets grey when set to read only. I just set all 4 of them to read only using:

```
tbPercentage.ReadOnly = true;
```

There is no other code that could conflict with it.

Comment: WPF? Winforms? asp? silverlight? the platform makes a difference. we need to know.

Comment: There must be more going on here.  Can you post some of your code?

Comment: You just said everything is normal but I have problems. That's not enough...

Comment: Without more information this question is useless and unanswerable.

Comment: It's Winforms... I'll post code for them now...

Comment: Just made i work by deleting the textbox, making a new one with same properties and same event handlers as the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made it work by deleting the textbox, making a new one with same properties and same event handlers as the old one.
There might be that designer generated code was not properly generated cause of 1 user control that had one bug.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a shot in the dark here and guess you are using winforms.

Also I am going to make another guess that you changed the background color on the text boxes that stay white and didn't change it on the one that grays out on read only mode.

Comment: Nope - same code for all 4...

Comment: Check the InitializeComponent code of the form load. If there is a backcolor being set the default behavior will not be followed.